# JQuery.each doesn't append items inside append

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append items inside a bootstrap row with data got from an API, so inside `$('CONTAINER').append(` i was doing a `each()` for each item in an object array, but instead, no items are appended it looks like that `each()` is ignored.

i'm using `this.taglio` as the following code is inside another `each()`

My code looks like this:

```js
$('<div>', {
  class: 'row'
}).append(
  $.each(this.tagli, function() {
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'col-md-3'
    }).append(
      $('<div>', {
        class: 'panel panel-default taglio'
      }).append(
        $('<div>', {
          class: 'panel-body'
        }).text(this.importo)))
  }),

  $('<div>', {
    class: 'col-md-3'
  }).append(
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'panel panel-default add'
    }).append(
      $('<div>', {
        class: 'panel-body text-center'
      }).text('+')).on('click', function() {
      $('#modalAdd').modal()
    }))
)
```

I'm using jquery 2.2.4

And only the div outside the .each is appended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each()` returns an object, not a HTML string which can be appended. To fix you issue you can change the logic to use `map()` to build a HTML string, something like this:

```js
let html = this.tagli.map(function(o) { 
  return '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="panel panel-default taglio"><div class="panel-body">' + o.importo + '</div></div></div>';
});
let $row = $('<div class="row" />').html(html);

$('<div class="col-md-3"><div class="panel panel-default add"><div class="panel-body text-center">+</div>').appendTo('#someElement');

$('#someElement').on('click', '.panel-body', function() {
  console.log('element clicked');
});

$('#modalAdd').modal()
```

Note that because there's so much HTML in the JS you may want to instead look at creating hidden template elements in the DOM which you `clone()` and amend in your loop before adding to the DOM.

Comment: How can i do it without using arrow function? i was trying to do something like `this.tagli.map(function(taglio) { return $('<div>')... })` but it's not working while with arrow function it does.. (i have to let it work on IE9..)

Comment: No problems, I've just updated the answer to use anonymous functions instead of arrow functions

Comment: does anonymous function in `.map()` only works with string? because i was trying the same solution with `this.tagli.map(function (o) { return $('<div>', { class: 'col-md3' }).append($('<div>', { class: 'panel panel-default taglio' }).append($('<div>', { class: 'panel-body text-center' }).text(o.importo)));})` but it doesn't work

Comment: while if i just change the `function (o) { return` with `o => ` it's working as have to

Comment: it's working but only with arrow function which i must avoid to use as it's unsupported in IE9..

Comment: My bad, I forgot template literals don't work in IE, updated again

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4b9dxL3g/ i actually made an example with and without arrow where only the arrow is rendered

Comment: okay it's working i had to surround `return $()` with `return ( $() )`